# Read & Set document Variables using Office JS and vice versa for VSTO Add-ins

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am working with office-js and VSTO add-ins.
Adding some variable using Word Add-in (VSTO) using the following code.:

```cs
doc.Variables.Add("XXXX","XXX Value");
```

Reading variables using following code:

```cs
foreach (Word.Variable v in doc.Variables) {
    if (v.Name == "XXXX"){ 
        // do something. 
    }
 }
```

Now I want to do same thing using an Office.js Add-in. I have tried following code:

```js
getCustomProperties(name: any) {
    var result = Office.context.document.settings.get(name);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}

setCustomProperties(name: any, value: any) {
    Office.context.document.settings.set(name, value);
    Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
}

RefreshSettings() {
    Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync(this.callback);
}
callback() {
    console.log("Refreshed");
}
```

But, I think this is different from what I am searching for.
Note : I also want to add variables using office-js and read if already added document variables.

I also found `DocumentProperties` but this is about the document only, and I can't add it.

Comment: Are you getting an error of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

Document variables are not yet supported in Office.js (please make sure to add/vote this request on our [uservoice channel](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word)), that said we do support the following (and i am not sure of your scenario but probably some of these options will be ok)

1. custom doc properties. there is a good sample [within Script Lab](http://aka.ms/scriptlab) that (check custom properties section). These are regular document properties and can be accessed by any Add-in activated on this document.
2. Settings. think about this as a property bag specifically for add-ins, will hold settings for each add-in instance within the document.

if you can share some insights on how you are using doc variables will be helpful to give you better guidance.

thanks!